# Is there a way to generate sample data out of a yang file

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

Our projects are based on yang modelling. there is a project which internally works on the modeled data of other projects.

So, to start with that project, we need to populate the models of other projects with the data in the data stores. this triggers the requirement of generating the sample data from a model

looking for the sample data preferable in XML/JSON format

Thanks
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:
1. Get a tool like yang browser from MG-Soft.
OR
2. Try downloading confd-basic (free from Tail-f/Cisco). Compile a project using your yang modules (use a sample project from their distro and add to it). Use the CLI and/or default values in the model to populate the database. Then export the database either using show [running-config]  |display [json|xml]. Or use netconf-console (also open-source) to perform a netconf "get-config" of the datastore and the result is xML.

Either approach will involve some learning curve & time investment but you'll get some long-term recurring benefits.